# Error while doing `eth_signTypedData` using Gnosis Safe via WalletConnect

Tags: ethers.js, gnosis-safe, walletconnect

I have been trying to do `eth_signTypedData` (by using ethers.js) while being connected to Gnosis Safe wallet via WalletConnect and receiving `{code: -32000, message: 'The address is invalid'}` error. I'm pretty confident that the error is coming from [here on this line](https://github.com/safe-global/safe-react-apps/blob/647dac4b6ce2994ce4bd73000ffd7c9833ff3627/apps/wallet-connect/src/hooks/useWalletConnect.tsx#L126) but cannot verify why addresses are not matching.

Side Note: Keeping everything the same but changing the method to `personal_sign` works perfectly. I'm having this problem only on `eth_signTypedData`

Adding the piece of code I'm using here for visualization even though I think it doesn't tell much about the problem:

```
const TYPES = {
        Agreement: [
            { name: 'active', type: 'address' },
            { name: 'passive', type: 'address' },
            { name: 'tokenURI', type: 'string' },
        ],
    }
    const domain = createSignatureDomain(chainId)
    const value = {
        active: claimantAddress,
        passive: issuerAddress,
        tokenURI: tokenUri,
    }
    const signature = await wallet._signTypedData(domain, TYPES, value)
```

Keeping everything the same but changing the method to `personal_sign` works perfectly. I'm having this problem only on `eth_signTypedData`.

Comment: This will be fixed soon https://github.com/safe-global/safe-apps-sdk/issues/363